# Jquery validate rules with custom function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-validate

I have table with dynamic rows create using jquery. I try to add required field validation for each row using my custom defined function but not working as expected.

please have a look below is screenshot of my dynamic table

[image]

my validation should work as following ways:

1. if there is only row present then show both field is required validation.

now below validation will apply if there is added more then one row

2. if I have entered item value but not entered quantity then it should show quantity is required
3. if I have entered quantity but not item field then it should show item field is required error message.
4. if both field is empty then ignore the row no need to do validation for that row.

below is my function developed in jquery :

```
$.validator.addMethod("sohil_test", function(value, element, options) {
        var selectors = options[1];
        var form = $(".compo_item_table").closest('form');
        var flag = true;

        var totalrows = form.find('tr.mainrow').length;

        $(form.find('tr.mainrow')).each(function () {
            var $row = $(this);
            var $elements = $row.find(selectors);

            var hasEmpty = $elements.filter(function (index) {
                return $(this).val();
            });

            if (hasEmpty.length)
            {
                $($row.find(selectors)).each(function () {
                    var missing = $(this).val() === "";

                    if(missing)
                    {
                        flag = false;
                    }
                });

            }else {
                $row.find(selectors).removeClass('error'); 
                console.log("ignore");

            }

        });
        return flag;


    }, $.validator.format("This field is reuired."));
```

if above function I call when form is submit like normal function we call using jquery then works ok but if I call same function using jquery validate rules like as below :

```
 "inventory_item[]": {
                     sohil_test: [1, '.common_class']

                 },
                 "item_quantity[]": {
                     sohil_test: [1, '.common_class'],

                 },
```

above is not working as expected. any solution is appreciated.